# Ubuntu Tablet on Nexus 7 - where is the new UI?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have followed both sets of instructions here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation but both methods are installing the Ubuntu Desktop to the device? This is quite an impressive feat on its own, but I have seen videos of people using the phone UI on a Nexus 7? Is there an alternative install that I can try to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you followed wrong tutorial.

That was to install ubuntu desktop on nexus 7.

Here is the actual,

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: Thank you, is there anything I can do from the device now its got ubuntu Desktop on? This install guide recommends you turn the device on etc and allow USB debugging but setting back to Android will take some time, is there a way I can avoid this process?

Comment: I am not sure. Because I don't own one. :) .. try `adb devices` while connected. I think it will be on.